# Spring Integration : listener of Inbound Gateway not working when implemented with @Gateway Interface

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

In my application, sending the messages to Tibco Queue with the help of Spring JMS Integration Outbound Gateway. We are having configuration file to load the Connection factory and all the information during server start up.

But when we try to retrieve the messages from Inbound Gateway, the call gets into the doReceive() of GenericMessagingTemplate class and not returned from that method.

Below is the configuration of our application

The Gateway Class as:

```
 @MessagingGateway 
 public Interface MessageGateway 
 {   
    @Gateway(requestChannel="InboundChannel")
    public Object listent(@Headers Map<String,Object> cusHeader, @Payload Object obj)
}
```

Below is the config and registers listener class:

```
public Class Msgconfig {

   @Bean
   public MessageChannel InboundChannel(){
      return new DirectChannel();
   }

   @Bean
   @ServiceActivator(inputChannel ="InboundChannel")
   public AbstractMessageHandler listenMessage() {
      // having the logic of DefaultMessageListenerContainer class to load connection factory and setting the message listener
    // Have the logic of ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener class to set the request channel
   }  
}
```

I have Custom Inbound class which overrides the handleMessageInternal() method which is actually used for handling the messages.

My client app or test call will call the MessageGateway.listen which has to return the JMS response which is not returning anything.

Can someone help me on this

Comment: There is not enough information in your question for anyone to help you; you need to provide much more detail. Using a listener container to process a request seems odd - it is for async inbound messaging. Have you tried enabling DEBUG logging and watching the messages flow through the application? Sounds like the reply is not being returned; you can add a reply timeout to the gateway to avoid the thread waiting for ever in `receive()`.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Actually as part of my implementation I need to listen the message using Inbound Gateway. In my case the message was already sent using Outbound gateway. The message which will be processed using Inbound gateway has to be customized for any client who wants to consume the message. Hope this explains my case and I need a solution for this problem. Also as you said tried with timeout and in that case it went TemporaryReplyChannel receive method, which doesn’t return any response

Comment: If it's request/reponse, why not use the JMS Outbound Gateway? You don't need to write any code for that.

Comment: Yes Gary, we are also using request/ response with Outbound Gateway but we are having one use case where we just want to receive or consume message. So have decided to use Inbound Gateway by configuring request channel and destination name. Also have noticed that in this case, it is calling doSendandReceive method instead of receive method. So stuck with how to proceed

Comment: You can't use a gateway for that; you should use an inbound channel adapter and a `@ServiceActivator` to invoke your code when a message arrives.

Comment: Yes Gary, that worked. Thanks

Comment: Shall I include reply channel on the Headers parameter while calling channel adapter. If yes, shall I include more than one reply channels. In my case I may receive messages from multiple response queues

Comment: The reply channel is not used in this context (one-way integration). If you have further questions, you should ask a new question, showing your current configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The `AbstractMessageHandler` indeed doesn't return anything. It is one-way component. If you would like to return something from downstream you have to use request-reply component. In the Spring Integration all of them are extension of the `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler`. However that's full unclear why you should go so low level - the simple POJO with the method to return anything for the gateway call is fully enough. You still can use that `@ServiceActivator` annotation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations